# Why Do My UICollectionViewCells Disappear After Scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout, but I am having issues with cells disappearing after I scroll down and back up.

Please see a [video demonstration](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6S1l9NPTGVON0lJTkhObi1WWUE/view?usp=sharing) of my issue.

I've done some Googling around and other people have related issues and I recognise that this is possibly due to cell reuse, but none of the answers I found elsewhere helped me.

So my questions are:

1. **Why is this happening?**
2. **How do I stop this from happening?**

Interestingly, once I present a `UIViewController` and dismiss it, the issue no longer occurs. Please see the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6S1l9NPTGVOS1dSUE1Jd3I2eTA/view?usp=sharing) of this in action.

NOTE: This bug has been here for a while (at least since iOS 10 and hasn't been fixed in iOS 11 beta 1 either).

*Edit 1*

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    switch (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row {
    case 0:
        // Speak Logo Cell
        let speakLogoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SpeakLogoCell", for: indexPath) as! SpeakLogoCell

        recordButton = speakLogoCell.recordButton

        return speakLogoCell
    case 1:
        // Text Input Cell
        let inputCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InputCell", for: indexPath) as! InputCell

        inputCell.inputTextView.delegate = self
        inputTextView = inputCell.inputTextView

        // Only restore input if launching and required.
        if currentlyLaunching && UserDefaultsHelper.loadShouldRestoreInput() {
            inputTextView!.text = UserDefaultsHelper.loadInput() ?? ""
        }

        return inputCell
    case 2:... // Continues for all the other cells
```

Comment: 1. iOS removed the cell in order to save resources because it was not displayed and you did not properly reinitialise it. 2. Properly reinitialise the cell. (Do you think we’re magicians and can really help you without any *relevant* code?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion to post some relevant code. I'm going to edit my question to include the appropriate part of the cellForItem method. Please let me know if you want anything else.

Comment: What is inputTextView?  Where is it stored?

Comment: inputTextView is a reference to a `UITextView` stored in the `UIViewController` which contains the `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. So the line of code that was causing the problem was actually in `viewDidAppear` and it was:

```
inputTextView?.becomeFirstResponder()
```

I have no idea why it caused the cell not to appear, but removing that line fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the fact that you're assigning the input view to a variable.  Generally I would just store the text from the input view in a variable rather than having a variable pointing to the textview itself.  You might change to that behavior and see if it changes, or just simply comment out the part where you set the input view to a variable for now and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I need a reference to this textfield so I can, for example, clear the textfield if the user presses the clear button.

Comment: So I've tried what you suggested (commented out setting the variable for now) and that did fix it. So I suppose that's helped isolate the problem, but it doesn't really help me implement a fix. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well you could store the text in a variable and set the textview's text to that variable in the cellforitem method, and then when they press clear you could clear the variable and reloadData on the collection view, or just reload the data at that index path.

Comment: Okay, and then presumably I’d update the text variable every time the text view’s text changes using the appropriate delegate method. I’ll give that a go, thanks

Comment: @LoicVerrall Cool glad it worked out. Please consider choosing my answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: unfortunately after a bit more testing, I discovered that the issue is still there somehow. Perhaps it’s something to do with my custom collection view layout class... 

Comment: Well from what I can tell you don't really have any repeated cell types.  Why not just use a UIScrollView?

Comment: To be honest this is causing me so much headache I might use one of my Developer TSI’s or even use a UITableView instead. Thanks for your help anyway!